# Should Access-Control-Allow-Methods include OPTIONS

Tags: cors

A CORS respecting client will issue an OPTIONS request before the actual request, in order to observe the Access-Control-* headers returned.

If I want a client to be able to POST an endpoint, is it sufficient with

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, GET, POST
```

Or do I also have to explicitly allow `OPTIONS`

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST
```

Comment: The CORS preflight OPTIONS request will work regardless of whether or not Access-Control-Allow-Methods includes OPTIONS. So it’s not necessary to include OPTIONS in the Access-Control-Allow-Methods value. Or rather, it would only be needed if you want to allow normal OPTIONS requests other than the CORS preflight OPTIONS request.

Comment: Consider this in terms of the browser behavior, and the call flow: (1) The browser first sends the CORS preflight OPTIONS request to the remote server to determine what methods the server allows, and then (2) the browser gets Access-Control-Allow-Methods back from the remote server. So, at step 1, prior to sending the CORS preflight OPTIONS requests, there’s no way the browser could know ahead of time whether or not, at step 2, the Access-Control-Allow-Methods sent back from the remote server will contain OPTIONS. So the browser always just sends the CORS preflight OPTIONS request, regardless.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My answer: **no**, and I've got 3 angles to argue from.

---

First, common sense. The `OPTIONS` HTTP method is the "API" for CORS authorization: the server permits or denies a particular cross-origin request in response to the corresponding `OPTIONS` "preflight" request (if one is needed¹). See [MDN CORS overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Now, a preflight with `Access-Control-Request-Method: OPTIONS` is nonsensical. That's because if `OPTIONS` requests had to be explicitly authorized by the server — the UA (User-Agent; the browser) would have no way to obtain that authorization. Because the way to obtain it is making an `OPTIONS` request. Observe the recursive self-dependency: the UA can only make an `OPTIONS` request... to obtain permission to make `OPTIONS` requests. That makes no sense.

In practice, supporting UAs well understand the semantics of CORS and don't require any permission to send `OPTIONS` preflights.

---

Second, read [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/SPSD-cors-20200602/). The W3 standard mandates the [resource sharing check](https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/SPSD-cors-20200602/#resource-sharing-check) only at these points:

- after [simple CORS request](https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/SPSD-cors-20200602/#simple-cross-origin-request-0);
- during the [actual request](https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/SPSD-cors-20200602/#actual-request) stage of ["not simple"](https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/SPSD-cors-20200602/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0) CORS request.

Crucially, [preflight request](https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/SPSD-cors-20200602/#preflight-request) is not `actual request`; and the rules of processing them *do not* mention the [resource sharing check](https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/SPSD-cors-20200602/#resource-sharing-check). The UA is not obliged to check permissions when sending preflights.

---

Third, read the source. To avoid *too theoretic* style of pitfalls — check a real browser-engine implementation. Like [Chromium](https://source.chromium.org/chromium).

Here, if you read C++, the function [`CheckAccessInternal()`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:services/network/public/cpp/cors/cors.cc;l=125-198) in `cors.cc` does all sorts of checks, along the lines of the `resource sharing check` from the standard. Also see [unit tests](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:services/network/public/cpp/cors/cors_unittest.cc;l=385-393).

However, preflight requests are not ye olde ajax; they're constructed by the browser internally; sent, checked and handled in [another place](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:services/network/public/cpp/cors/cors_unittest.cc;l=385-393): `cors_url_loader.cc`. There you can see, no calls to `CheckAccessInternal()` or anything like that.

This is to say that a preflight request with `Access-Control-Request-Method: OPTIONS` makes no sense; likewise, the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS` has no effect (unless of course you reuse the `OPTIONS` method for something else in your webapp).

---

¹ preflights are skipped with [simple cross-origin requests](https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/SPSD-cors-20200602/#simple-cross-origin-request) and on [preflight result cache](https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/SPSD-cors-20200602/#preflight-result-cache-0) hit.

Comment: Brilliant answer. Every word of this is wholly correct.

Answer (score -2):

`GET` does not need `OPTIONS` for a typical CORS host setup, but `POST` could, depending on the `Content-Type` and/or the encoding. I suggest you enable `OPTIONS`.

You can read the [CORS spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/SPSD-cors-20200602/) to learn about the convoluted situations where OPTIONS is needed, or you could just enable it.

Comment: Thanks, bad example from my side to not mention POST. I’ll update the question so it makes more sense. The question is about whether OPTIONS is needed.

Comment: Why do you suggest that OPTIONS be enabled?

Comment: I answered that question, and suggested that you should enable it even if you think you might not need it (yet). It is amazing how requirements change just a little, and then you have a bug that is hard to find. Enabling OPTIONS now could save you a headache later.

Comment: Section 7.1.5 of the CORS spec that you linked has an example that suggest OPTIONS is not needed in the Allow-Methods header.

Comment: I understand. Like I said, you do not need OPTIONS right now, but you very well might soon... and then you will have to go back and figure stuff out all over again.

Comment: @MikeSlinn Your comments are wildly speculative. The CORS specification has never required `OPTIONS` to be listed in the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header for preflight to succeed and there is no plan to change that; I suspect that such a change would indeed break cross-origin access to many CORS-aware resources.

Comment: @jub0bs Regarding comments, "wildly speculative" is hyperbole.