# CORS, HttpOnly, CSRFCookie; Django; ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, django, http, cors, django-cors-headers

I am developing a webApp. My backend is on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000 and my frontend is on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000. I am using Django and ReactJS. I have configured my CORS policies on the backend to allow only my fronted to make requests.

So. Whenever I have to get CSRF cookies from my backend they come in a response under `Set-Cookie` with `HttpOnly` flag.

My question is if we are not supposed to extract HttpOnly cookies with the JS how come I still can do that with my ReactJS app. However, whenever I remove that flag I cannot set or retrieve those cookies from the header anymore. Whta is wrong? Or what is right?

Help me to understand that please.

my django CORS setup:

```
# CSRF Cookie Settings
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE: Optional[int] = None

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:3000'
]

CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True

# CORS(cross origin resource sharing) settings
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:3000',
]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
'DELETE',
'GET',
'PATCH',
'POST',
'PUT',
]
```

my reactjs request:

```
fetch("http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:8000/get_csrf",{
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials:'same-origin',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(...response.headers)
        response.json()
      })
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(this.getCookie('csrftoken'))
        },

        (error) => {

        }
      )
```

Comment: You say `this.getCookie('csrftoken')` which should in your code end up meaning `window.getCookie('csrftoken')`? You are not getting the cookies from the response you are getting the cookie from your own frontend. Also you have `credentials` set to `same-origin`? That won't work with CORS requests...

Comment: you are right about cookies. But if I set cookies to some other value it does not work and says that the server does not allow requests from this origin even though I set it there

Comment: You haven't added `OPTIONS` to `CORS_ALLOW_METHODS`, when a `POST` or other request which changes data is made there is usually a preflight request using the `OPTIONS` method. If `OPTIONS` isn't allowed CORS won't work in this case...

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now I get the cookies set up in the browser. However, I cannot extract them with the JS anymore. I need to include them into the ```X-CSRFToken``` header to use other endpoints.

Comment: Sorry to bother you too much with this, but now I have ```OPTIONS``` included and ```credentials:'include'``` in the fetch request headers. Even though the browser sets the cookies I cannot extract them to use them in the ```X-CSRFToken``` header later. What should I do?

Comment: Your url is of the form `/get_csrf` usually a url like that would imply that the server will return the CSRF token in the _response body_ as JSON or however you implement it, why are you not getting it from there?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat No, `OPTIONS` doesn't need to be listed in the preflight response's `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header for preflight to succeed.

Comment: @jub0bs now that I look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66926518/should-access-control-allow-methods-include-options) it makes sense that it won't be needed.

Comment: I have removed the ```OPTIONS``` method from there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have gathered a bit more information and have found out how to set it up correctly.

1. Yes, we cannot access `HttpOnly` cookies.
2. Need to have `credentials:'include'` in the fetch JS request.
3. Need to have `mode: 'cors'` in the fetch JS request.
4. In Django `settings.py`:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000',
]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]

CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = [
    'Date'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

You cannot.

### More details

> My backend is on xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:8000 and my frontend is on xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:3000.

Note that your request is *cross-origin*.

Be aware that the [Fetch Standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) (the de facto CORS specification) categorises `Set-Cookie` as a [*forbidden response-header name*](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name). Therefore, regardless of the server's CORS configuration, browsers [do not allow](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-forbidden-response-header-name%E2%91%A0) a client to read such headers from the response to a cross-origin request.

The [MDN Web Docs about the `Set-Cookie` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie), which may be a nonauthoritative source of truth but is easier to read than the Fetch Standard, contains this clarifying warning:

> Browsers block frontend JavaScript code from accessing the `Set-Cookie` header, as required by the Fetch spec, which defines `Set-Cookie` as a forbidden response-header name that must be filtered out from any response exposed to frontend code.